Double recursion with vectors
I'm trying to figure out how double recursions work in the following example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int F(std::vector<int> &v, int a, int &b) {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 2) return a;
    b -= 1;
    a = F(v, a - 1, b) + F(v, a, b);
    v.push_back(a);
    return a;
}
    
int main(){
   std::vector<int> v;
   int b = 7;
   F(v, 15, b);
   for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
       std::cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}

OUTPUT:

21 33 46 60 75

I understand how 21 got pushed into the vector. But after that, I don't understand which recursion (left or right) is then called, and how to follow that until the correct output.
Could you please explain to me, step by step, how this particular program is executed?

The expression you wrote F(v, a - 1, b) + F(v, a, b) contains two subexpressions (the two calls) that can be evaluated in any order. The order is unspecified. Therefore, it does not make much sense to reason about the order of the elements of v. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order.

this is from DSA (data structures and algorithms) exam, we do it on paper without any help of PC or books

Whoever wrote the text of this particular exam isn't qualified to do so. That, or the intention is to create a silly "gotcha" question where the only right answer is: you cannot predict the output as the evaluation order of the recursive calls is unspecified.

do you know how this should be written in order output to be "predictable" on paper?

It will produce that output if the left call is evaluated first: https://godbolt.org/z/Kvhs5eh1z

@MarcoBonelli that's the nature of DSA courses almost everywhere - what they use is quite incorrect "ideal" case of C or C++ code, and result never should be used in practice. They used Pascal in past which didn't had these "questionable" situations.

@codproe yes: auto left = F(v, a - 1, b); auto right = F(v, a, b); a = left + right; would be fine.

thank you very much, so could you explain how this double recursion works step by step to get correct output, assuming that left recursion is first executed... may you post detailed answer?

assuming that left recursion is first executed -- Rewrite your code as described by @MarcoBonelli, and then use a debugger to step through your program.  Then you can adjust the amount of "detail" you will get, as you will see step-by-step what is occurring.

As @PaulMcKenzie states. Or you know.. just add a few prints.

when you separate them into two orders that seems just like totally different task, and it makes sense to go through it just using paper :) thank you very much, all of you

@codproe yes the task is different, but now the behavior is fully deterministic because you know the order of evaluation and you can correctly predict the output. The original task was simply ill formed.

@codproe "Could you please explain to me, step by step, how this particular program is executed?" - that is what your debugger is meant for. Step through the code at runtime and watch what it actually does.

C++17:

17 Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

The output that you have posted, will be generated only when compiler will perform evaluation of subexpression F(v, a - 1, b) before F(v, a, b) in every evaluation of expression F(v, a - 1, b) + F(v, a, b).
A quick check you can do by swapping the operands (subexpression) - F(v, a, b) + F(v, a - 1, b). With this, you may get a different output.
The recursive call trace for the given expression will be like a binary tree but there is catch here - the parameter b of function F() is a reference. Which means, any change in value b will reflect everywhere it's been referred.
For the given value of parameter a and b (a = 15 and b = 7), once the value of b will become 2, the condition b <= 2 will be satisfied and rest of the recursive calls to F() function will simply return value of a (whatever it is passed as argument in that call to function F()).
Assume, in every call to function F(), when evaluating expression F(v, a - 1, b) + F(v, a, b) expression, compiler evaluates subexpression F(v, a - 1, b) first, this is how the recursion tree will be:
(C1)         [Initial value of args - a = 15, b = 7]  F(v, a, b)  ==> returned value discarded
                                                           |
                                                +-------------------+
                                                |                   |
(C2)                                      F(v, 14, b)         F(v, 15, b) ==> a = 60 + 15 => 75 (pushed and returned)
                                                |  
                                       +-----------------+
                                       |                 |
(C3)                             F(v, 13, b)        F(v, 14, b) ==> a = 46 + 14 => 60 (pushed and returned)
                                       |
                              +-----------------+
                              |                 |
(C4)                    F(v, 12, b)        F(v, 13, b) ==> a = 33 + 13 => 46 (pushed and returned)
                              |
                     +-----------------+
                     |                 |
(C5)           F(v, 11, b)        F(v, 12, b) ==> a = 21 + 12 => 33 (pushed and returned)
                     |
value of b calcul-   |
ated to 2   +-----------------+     +-val returned-+
            |                 |     |              v
(C6)   F(v, 10, 2)        F(v, 11, 2) ==> a = 10 + 11 => 21 (pushed and returned)   
           \     |             /              ^
            \    +------------/-val returned--+
             \_______________/
                     |
                     v
              Both these calls will return the value of
              parameter a received (i.e. 10 and 11) because 
              value of parameter b is 2 now.

              Stack will windup from here.
              All the pending calls to function F() (right subtree's), in the 
              stack, will just return the value of parameter a.

Hence, the output you are getting:
21 33 46 60 75


thank you very much. First time when a=21 is pushed into vector, the next line of code after push_back(a) is return a, so I don't understand how program continues further if a is returned? It should stop right there and vector should have only one element. Could you please clarify this?

In the ascii art, on L.H.S you can see C1, C2 and so on. They mean Call 1, Call 2 of function F(). C6 is the final call to function F() for the given values of a and b. After this, the stack created by recursive calls of function F(), starts winding up. In C6, it pushes 21 to vector which is also the first element and after this it returns 21 to previous call of function F(), which is F(v, 11, b). In the ascii art, the R.H.S is shows the wind up (recursive call return), read it from bottom to up -C6->C5.. so on. Every right subtree will just return val of a.

contd.. In C5, F(v, 11, b) will return 21 (value of a returned from C6) and F(v, 12, b) will return just the value of a, which is 12. In C5, now we have values from both subexpression, so, value of a will be calculated a = 21 + 12 = 33. This value will be pushed in vector and returned back to C4 call of function F(v, 12, b) and the same steps performed in C4 and so on.. Let me know, if you have any further question.

In short
The precedence rules of C++ do not define if the left or the right term of your double recursion is called first.  In fact,  depending on the order chosen by the compiler,  you may obtain different results with the same code.
In depth demonstration
From your OP:
if (a <= 0 || b <= 2) return a;

Above is the base case that helps keep the recursion from recursing forever.
a = F(v, a - 1, b) + F(v, a, b);
v.push_back(a);


assuming that left recursion is first executed

The first term is call (per assumption). Initially b=7, a=15. Then since a is immediately decremented in the call and b is decremented inside F, both a and b decrease together. Since a-b > 2, the base case will hit b == 2 before a <=0.
In the recursion, the first term is called again and again until b == 2. Only then is the 2nd term called and now a is not decremented in the call. Inside the 2nd F, the first F is called again (per your assumption). This time, b is still 2 as it is not decremented until after the base case. In your debugger, be sure to observe the Call Stack and watch the recursions unwind.
One tricky item. The arg a when calling the first F is one less than the arg a when calling the second F. Just keep point in mind.
I was curious how different the results might be. The variations are controlled by an added a-1 flag, flag_am1.
flag_am1 = 1: Deterministic with the a-1 term evaluated first.
flag_am1 = 0: Deterministic with the a-1 term evaluated second.
flag_am1 = -1: Identical to the OP
flag_am1 = -2: Similar to the OP except that the order of the two functions are swapped.
Note that for the flag_am1 = -2 case,
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int F(std::vector<int>& v, int a, int& b, int flag_am1) {
   // std::cout << flag_am1 << ": ENTER: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
   if (a <= 0 || b <= 2)
   {
      std::cout << flag_am1 << ": EXIT:  a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      return a;
   }
   b -= 1;
   if (flag_am1 == 1)
   {
      // std::cout << "1.0: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      a = F(v, a - 1, b, flag_am1);
      std::cout << "1.1: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      a += F(v, a, b, flag_am1);
      std::cout << "1.2: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
   }
   else if (flag_am1 == 0)
   {
      // std::cout << "0.0: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      a = F(v, a, b, flag_am1);
      std::cout << "0.1: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      a += F(v, a - 1, b, flag_am1);
      std::cout << "0.2: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
   }
   else if (flag_am1 == -1) // like the OP
   {
      std::cout << "-1.0: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      a = F(v, a - 1, b, flag_am1) + F(v, a, b, flag_am1);
      std::cout << "-1.1: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
   }
   else{ // flag_am1 == -2
      std::cout << "-2.0: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
      a = F(v, a, b, flag_am1) + F(v, a - 1, b, flag_am1);
      std::cout << "-2.1: a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
   }
   v.push_back(a);
   std::cout << " ** v.push_back(" << a << ")" << std::endl;
   return a;
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v{};
   int b = 7;

   v.resize(0);
   b = 7;
   std::cout << "\t *** a-1 flag is 1" << std::endl;
   F(v, 15, b, 1);
   for (int i = 0;i < v.size();i++)
   {
      std::cout << v[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;

   v.resize(0);
   b = 7;
   std::cout << "\t *** a-1 flag is 0" << std::endl;
   F(v, 15, b, 0);
   for (int i = 0;i < v.size();i++)
   {
      std::cout << v[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;

   v.resize(0);
   b = 7;
   std::cout << "\t *** a-1 flag is -1 (effectively like the OP)" << std::endl;
   F(v, 15, b, -1); // like original OP
   for (int i = 0;i < v.size();i++)
   {
      std::cout << v[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;

   v.resize(0);
   b = 7;
   std::cout << "\t *** a-1 flag is -2 (similar to OP but two F terms reversed)" << std::endl;
   F(v, 15, b, -2); // like original OP except the a-1 term is 2nd
   for (int i = 0;i < v.size();i++)
   {
      std::cout << v[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
}

The important thing to remember when looking at the four sets of outputs, for cases flag_am1 = -1 or = -2, your results may vary.
Output:
         *** a-1 flag is 1
1: EXIT:  a=10 b=2
1.1: a=10 b=2
1: EXIT:  a=10 b=2
1.2: a=20 b=2
 ** v.push_back(20)
1.1: a=20 b=2
1: EXIT:  a=20 b=2
1.2: a=40 b=2
 ** v.push_back(40)
1.1: a=40 b=2
1: EXIT:  a=40 b=2
1.2: a=80 b=2
 ** v.push_back(80)
1.1: a=80 b=2
1: EXIT:  a=80 b=2
1.2: a=160 b=2
 ** v.push_back(160)
1.1: a=160 b=2
1: EXIT:  a=160 b=2
1.2: a=320 b=2
 ** v.push_back(320)
20 40 80 160 320 

         *** a-1 flag is 0
0: EXIT:  a=15 b=2
0.1: a=15 b=2
0: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
0.2: a=29 b=2
 ** v.push_back(29)
0.1: a=29 b=2
0: EXIT:  a=28 b=2
0.2: a=57 b=2
 ** v.push_back(57)
0.1: a=57 b=2
0: EXIT:  a=56 b=2
0.2: a=113 b=2
 ** v.push_back(113)
0.1: a=113 b=2
0: EXIT:  a=112 b=2
0.2: a=225 b=2
 ** v.push_back(225)
0.1: a=225 b=2
0: EXIT:  a=224 b=2
0.2: a=449 b=2
 ** v.push_back(449)
29 57 113 225 449

         *** a-1 flag is -1 (effectively like the OP)
-1.0: a=15 b=6
-1.0: a=14 b=5
-1.0: a=13 b=4
-1.0: a=12 b=3
-1.0: a=11 b=2
-1: EXIT:  a=10 b=2
-1: EXIT:  a=11 b=2
-1.1: a=21 b=2
 ** v.push_back(21)
-1: EXIT:  a=12 b=2
-1.1: a=33 b=2
 ** v.push_back(33)
-1: EXIT:  a=13 b=2
-1.1: a=46 b=2
 ** v.push_back(46)
-1: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
-1.1: a=60 b=2
 ** v.push_back(60)
-1: EXIT:  a=15 b=2
-1.1: a=75 b=2
 ** v.push_back(75)
21 33 46 60 75

         *** a-1 flag is -2 (similar to OP but two F terms reversed)
-2.0: a=15 b=6
-2.0: a=15 b=5
-2.0: a=15 b=4
-2.0: a=15 b=3
-2.0: a=15 b=2
-2: EXIT:  a=15 b=2
-2: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
-2.1: a=29 b=2
 ** v.push_back(29)
-2: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
-2.1: a=43 b=2
 ** v.push_back(43)
-2: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
-2.1: a=57 b=2
 ** v.push_back(57)
-2: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
-2.1: a=71 b=2
 ** v.push_back(71)
-2: EXIT:  a=14 b=2
-2.1: a=85 b=2
 ** v.push_back(85)
29 43 57 71 85


A very interesting answer.  I've made a little edit to put the most important part of your message first, so that readers do not miss it if they dont' read up to the end.  If you don't agree, don't hesitate to rollback.

@Christophe, Thanks. Good to add the BLUF.

thank you very much, detailed explanation
